# Rogue program disabled access to Firefox's "Get add-ons" and "Extensions". How can I get them back?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, firefox-extensions, malware

After installing a program called "FreeFileViewer", the program disabled access to Firefox's "Get add-ons" and "Extensions" options.  To make matters worse, it installed the Yahoo! toolbar that I now can't remove (because it disabled Firefox's options to do so).

Please help. Any advice you can give me to restore these Firefox options would be greatly appreciated!

BTW, I am running Firefox 15.0.1 on a Windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 0):

This program install an other program called *InstalllQ*, an adware from the site *w3i.com* which is the source of the problem.

**FYI:**

Web Of Trust rating for w3i.com: [WOT rating w3i.com](http://www.mywot.com/en/scorecard/w3i.com?utm_source=addon&utm_content=warn-viewsc)

**The solution:**

**1)** Download and install RKill form Bleeping Computer *and run it*:

[RKill download Web page](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/rkill/)

**2)** Download (from the official Web site), install, *update and run MalwareByte*

[Official MalwareByte download Web page](http://www.malwarebytes.org/products/malwarebytes_free/)

Normally this is enough to fix the problem.

Comment: **WARNING:** WOT-ratings may be (partly) ok, but do **NOT install any WOT-software**, it can/must be considered as malware!!! - https://thehackernews.com/2016/11/web-of-trust-addon.html